# App crashes after import the GooglePlayGamesPlugin and GoogleMobileAds unitypackages

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-mobile-ads

I imported to my unity project the GooglePlayGamesPlugin and GoogleMobileAds unitypackages
After import, the unity console does not show any errors. I built the project and installed it on a smartphone for testing. When I try to launch the app it immediately crashes and show the error "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped". If I importe separate the GoogleMobileAds or GooglePlayGamesPlugin then the app works. I suspect that errors occurred due to different versions of libraries in the Editor folder.

[image]

I use:

- Unity - 3.2f1
- GooglePlayGamesPlugin - 0.9.58
- GoogleMobileAds - 3.15.1

I tried to fix the error as follows:

- Created a new empty project and imported the GooglePlayGamesPlugin and GoogleMobileAds unitypackages
- I deleted the old version of the file
- I clicked Android solver -> solve

The code has no errors, because even in the empty project, this error occurred

How can this be fixed ? 
In my project, I want to use both the GooglePlayGamesPlugin and GoogleMobileAds.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don’t use google services in unity but why don’t you try to use UnityAds instead of google mobile ads ?

https://unity.com/solutions/unity-ads